# How can I trigger detection for Microsoft-Defender/AV using a pseudo-threat?

Tags: antivirus, windows-defender, antivirus-integration, microsoft365-defender

How can I trigger the Microsoft AV to detect a file or URL as malicious using a pseudo-threat? A pseudo-threat in this case is a 'clean/safe' file but is detected by the Microsoft AV (or the AV industry as a whole) as malicious just for testing.

Is it still via EICAR testing? Or is there some other way aside from EICAR? How about URL-pseudo threats?

Thank you very much.